# Return column name if result is true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got an Excel file that I need to manipulate in SQL. I've imported the file but need to show the primary key (MI_KEY) and the column name where the result is true/1.

My table is laid out like the below:

```
MI_KEY          TEST_1_FIELD          TEST_2_FIELD          TEST_3_FIELD          TEST_4_FIELD
123bg-fd23           1                     1                     0                     0
2873g-fht5           0                     0                     0                     0
23jdd-sd43           1                     0                     1                     1
23jfk-4kff           0                     1                     1                     1
```

I want to return the MI_KEY and the column name where the result is true, for example;

```
  MI_KEY           ISSUE
123bg-fd23      TEST_1_FIELD
123bg-fd23      Test_2_FIELD
23jdd-sd43      TEST_1_FIELD
23jdd-sd43      TEST_3_FIELD
23jdd-sd43      TEST_4_FIELD
23jfk-4kff      TEST_2_FIELD
23jfk-4kff      TEST_3_FIELD
23jfk-4kff      TEST_4_FIELD
```

It's probably important to let you know that this will need to be dynamic as different files could have different header names so I don't want to hard code if it can be helped.

Comment: UNION ALL, one select per TEST_n_FIELD.

Answer (score 3):

You can unpivot using `apply` and then filter:

```
select t.MI_KEY, v.which
from t cross apply
     (values ('TEST_1_FIELD', TEST_1_FIELD),
             ('TEST_2_FIELD', TEST_2_FIELD),
             ('TEST_3_FIELD', TEST_3_FIELD)
     ) v(which, val)
where val = 1;
```

This assumes that "true" means the value is `1`.

To make this dynamic, you will need to generate the list of columns for each table.  That requires dynamic SQL.

If this is the case, I would suggest that you have a problem with your data model.  You could instead be storing the base data as a single table with three columns, instead of tables with a variable number of columns.

Comment: Thanks :) Seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using union all

```
select MI_KEYINT MI_KEY, "TEST_1_FIELD" as ISSUE from test_db.test_5 where  TEST_1_FIELD = 1
union all select MI_KEYINT MI_KEY, "TEST_2_FIELD" as ISSUE from test_db.test_5 where TEST_2_FIELD = 1
union all select MI_KEYINT MI_KEY, "TEST_3_FIELD"  as ISSUE from test_db.test_5 where TEST_3_FIELD = 1
union all select MI_KEYINT MI_KEY, "TEST_4_FIELD"  as ISSUE from test_db.test_5 where TEST_4_FIELD = 1
```

Result

```
MI_KEY    |ISSUE       |
----------|------------|
123bg-fd23|TEST_1_FIELD|
23jdd-sd43|TEST_1_FIELD|
123bg-fd23|TEST_2_FIELD|
23jfk-4kff|TEST_2_FIELD|
23jdd-sd43|TEST_3_FIELD|
23jfk-4kff|TEST_3_FIELD|
23jdd-sd43|TEST_4_FIELD|
23jfk-4kff|TEST_4_FIELD|
```

If it is to be dynamic then i assume your db creates a new column every time a field comes with a new column name, hence complexity

Comment: I'm never really a fan of the `UNION ALL` solution. It end up with *N* +1 number of scans of the table (Where *N* is number of `UNION` clauses). Using `VALUES` to unpivot the data only results in 1. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5bdb90f216ea58f8b4c1ab61280ed96)

Comment: Then this answer is only for light weight data